# vs code ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyodbc when starting local copy of Azure serverless functions (python)

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, azure-functions

I have a new machine and I am having issues getting Azure serverless functions to run in vs Code.  They ran fine on my old machine - which has since died so I can't reference the settings and installs there :(

- Win11
- Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM) - 15.0.2000.5 (X64)
- Python 3.11
  I have cloned the github repo to my machine and installed (I think) all the Azure extensions required. When I try to run the debugger NO CORS: Attach To Python Functions. The build script

> pip install -r requirements.txt

runs but gives me an error message

```
Installing collected packages: pyodbc, certifi, azure-functions, xmltodict, urllib3, six, numpy, idna, colorama, charset-normalizer, requests, python-dateutil, click, stripe, pandas, kml2geojson
Attempting uninstall: pyodbc
Found existing installation: pyodbc 4.0.35
Uninstalling pyodbc-4.0.35:
  Successfully uninstalled pyodbc-4.0.35
DEPRECATION: pyodbc is being installed using the legacy 'setup.py install' method, because it does not have a 'pyproject.toml' and the 'wheel' package is not installed. pip 23.1 will enforce this behaviour change. A possible replacement is to enable the '--use-pep517' option. Discussion can be found at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8559
Running setup.py install for pyodbc ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  × Running setup.py install for pyodbc did not run successfully.
```

If I run the command with the --use-pep517 then I get a different eror message

```
ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyodbc
Failed to build pyodbc
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyodbc, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I can run the command pip install pyodbc  with no issues.

My requirements.txt looks like this..

```
azure-functions==1.8.0
certifi==2021.10.8
charset-normalizer==2.0.9
idna==3.3
pyodbc==4.0.32
requests==2.26.0
stripe==2.64.0
urllib3==1.26.7
pandas==1.3.5
xmltodict==0.12.0
kml2geojson==5.0.1
```

and I have my local database credentials set up in my local.settings.json

```json
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "server":"RAZERPRO17", 
    "database" : "MyDatabase", 
    "uname" : "MyUser", 
    "password" : "MyPassword",
    "stripe_api_key" : "sk_test_.........",
    "google_map_id" : "https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/embed?mid=.......
}
```

I'm not sure what to look for next to resolve the issue.
Python is in my path at C:\Python311 and I can run other python files without an issue.
pip is up to date (V23.0.1)

My host file looks like this:

```json
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[1.*, 2.0.0)"
  }
}
```

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I updated the requirents.txt to pyodbc=4.0.35 and now the install script works.  Locally running functions still fails though because Python 3.11 is not supported.

I have had to download Python 3.9.13 and update the .venv file to use the older version of python